# .NET and Configuration Files With DLLS

Tags: c#, .net

I am somewhat familiar with using configuration in .NET, but I am a little bit confused about something. You create an App.Config file to go with your exe, and any dlls you create use the same configuration file.

So how do you access the config in the configuration file from within your DLL? If you create a settings.settings inside the DLL project in Visual Studio it ends up blank with no settings in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to share the application settings file for all of your dlls.

So you must have a different section inside this config file for each referenced assembly...

Comment: Right. I added some settings into the settings.settings file, and it created an app.config for me inside the dll project. The app.config had the settings inside a section which included the namespace of the dll. I think all I need to do then is move the settings into the app.config that goes with the exe project, and delete the app.config in the dll project

Comment: My problem is actually a bit more complicated than that because I want to instantiate dlls dynamically, etc. But I will have to sort that out when I get there.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) class to get the settings from the app.config (or web.config) from within a DLL.  The [AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) property will get the data from the appSettings section of the config file.

```
NameValueCollection settings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
string keyValue = settings["SomeKey"];
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do what you are asking (use the app.config file from your DLL project rather than or in addition to the app.config file for the EXE file that is using the DLL.)

See post #3 from this thread:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/226001-problem-app-config-dll

Comment: Yeah, but I don't really need to have two app.config files. I can just use the one in the exe project. When I added something to the settings.settings file in the dll project it generated the app.config in the dll project. I plan to delete it.

Comment: Thanks though, the answers so far have been very helpful.